# Determine Keybinding Strings For Gamepad

Tags: games, shortcut-keys, gamepad

I want to manually map the commands to the game Assault Cube to my PS3 controller.

From what I understand, I can do so by making the correct adjustment to the configuration file. Here is a snippet of that configuration file:

```
bind "MOUSE1" [attack]
bind "MOUSE2" [altaction]
editbind "MOUSE2" [ showmenu editing ]
bind "MOUSE3" [weapon]
bind "MOUSE4" [ universaldelta 1 ]
bind "MOUSE5" [ universaldelta -1 ]
bind "BACKSPACE" [dropflag]
editbind "BACKSPACE" [delent]
bind "TAB" [ showscores 1; onrelease [ showscores 0 ] ]
```

The problem is I have no idea how to determine what strings need to be used to map these commands to my PS3 controller.

How do I determine this? Is there a command line option that will let me input buttons from the PS3 controller that will give me the corresponding strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to determine my PS3 controller's mapping by installing and using jstest-gtk, a command-line based program. It worked!